# how to find out the point of intersection of a circular arc and a circle

Tags: equation-solving

I have a circular arc.I know is centre radius and angle range.I need a matlab code to check whether a circle with known values intersects the arc and at which point they intersect.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout Circle intersection equations. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circle-CircleIntersection.html